# Use $in for id field on embedded DBRef object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, dbref

I want to use $in for id field of inner DBRef object and do in such a way:

```
{users: {$elemMatch: {device: {'$ref': 'devices', '$id' : { "$in" : [ 'deviceId' ] }}}}}
```

In response I get nothing(but I should).

If I query on exact id it works ok:

```
{users: {$elemMatch: {device: {'$ref': 'devices', '$id' : "deviceId"}}}}
```

So my question is if it possible to query with $in and how I can do that.

UPD: 
Here is my document example:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId
    name: "group name"
    users: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId
            device: DBRef('devices', 'deviceId', undefined)
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us a document example.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit added it to question